# PHP.ini custom session.save_path Permission denied

Tags: php, session, php7

I use

- Centos 7 (latest update)
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.2

I would like to change the directory where sessions stored on the server, the default directory is `/var/lib/php/session/`, I can use this directory without any problem, but when I change the directory in `PHP.ini` file, I get an error :

```
session_start(): open(/var/www/session/sess_dug784eu96aj06eh1gte4hak2f, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I also edited `php.conf` inside `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and removed this line To stop session directory from being overridden :

```
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
```

As you can see, I use `/var/www/session/` as new directory to store sessions and this directory exist and have exactly same Permission as default directory :

```
0770 / owner : root / group : Apache
```

I also tried to copy the existing session file from default directory to the new directory, but I still get same error !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What user/group is the PHP script running as?

Comment: Under user and groupe Apache @womble

Comment: Presumably it's an SELinux issue, then.

Comment: Can you give me a clue how to find out please ? @womble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution, THX @womble to point where the problem is, I could at least search on the correct way,

In case if someone else have same problem, SELinux most be Disabled (which is not recommended), or it most be configured to allow Apache access the new directory :

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/session -R
```